# What motivates the Unsullied to follow orders?

Tags: game-of-thrones

The [Wiki](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Unsullied) writes:

> Because they are eunuchs, the Unsullied will not succumb to bloodthirsty [sic] or sexual urges in the midst of battle; their actions will only go as far as what they have been ordered to do, and nothing more. The Unsullied also seem resistant and even immune to pain. However, Unsullied do possess emotions and can show anger.

They can be traded so they are loyal to no one. They fear nothing so there is no faith.

And they feel no pain nor desire.

Then what drives them? What is the motivation for them to follow orders?

Comment: I think it's clear that they feel stuff. They aren't automatons in the story. Grey Worm is much more than an unfeeling husk of a man. Also - curious what you mean by "they fear nothing so there is no faith."

Comment: Idk if they have shown this in the show but in the books, Unsullied are trained to obey their masters beyond the point of reason. They find it easier to die than to disobey. So motivation would be indoctrination.

Comment: @MishaRosnach I believe the OP meant since they don't fear anything, they don't fear death and what will happen after they die (presuming other GoT characters have faiths that includes an afterlife). This means there is a direct correlation between fear and life after death.

Comment: @apollo I believe he meant "Death is the worst thing that could happen to a man due to disobedience of his master/lord. If unsullied do not fear even death or pain, what makes them obey their masters"?

Comment: @Aegon I only meant for the part where OP uses "fear" and "no faith" in the same sentence to describe the state of The Unsullied. Of course, OP is asking something else. I was just pointing out a potential comment/idea about user MishaRosnach comment/question above.

Comment: @apollo If that's the case, I think it might be a bit presumptuous. Fear of death isn't the only known source of faith.

Comment: @MishaRosnach I agree.

Comment: What motivates you to follow orders from your boss? From your government?

Comment: Not sure about the tv series, but the Unsullied from book follow a religion of their own. **_The goddess is called by many names. She is the Lady of Spears, the Bride of Battle, the Mother of Hosts, but her true name belongs only to these poor ones who have burned their manhoods upon her altar. We may not speak of her to others._**

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Paycheck from Boss and Facilities and rights from Government.

Comment: @SorrelVesper: Right, well I imagine the food and lodgings provided by the slave owners are considered a good reason to keep working. Beyond that, well, they've been brainwashed haven't they.

Comment: I agree with @LightnessRacesinOrbit and I have to add that when someone is trained/fashioned in a certain way from the childhood, they do not even thinking of finding an alternative or escaping since they have brainwashed them to the greatest extent. They have made it built-in into their minds to follow commands. They have no other reason to live than to follow orders. If I remember correctly, it is mentioned in the show that the boys are taken in young age. so there you go.

Answer (score 6):

The Unsullied follow orders because they are trained to do so. They go through a very rigorous and painful training process, which starts at a young age. It is described in great detail in the books. To oversimplify, they are conditioned like Pavlov's dogs.

Also, IIRC, they can only be sold once after their training is complete, and their loyalty to their owner is absolute. I do not think they can be re-sold to another owner.

I believe the emotions that we see displayed by Grey Worm result from the fact that Dany, unlike a typical owner of the Unsullied, treats him like a human being.

Comment: You got my upvote, but masters demanded the return of the unsullied to be auctioned, isn't that so? I think they can be resold. Maybe their conditioning is to the whip. Before attacking Astapor, I remember someone telling Dany, "You hold the whip now, they are yours." or something similar.

Comment: @C.Koca, IIRC, there is no demand to return the Unsullied in the books, although it's been a while since I've read them.

Comment: you are correct. But books are lagging. And the question has show tag.

Answer (score 5):

Following up on the comment I made the day this question was posted, I have re-watched the episodes and I can confirm the show has also showed the extensive training and indoctrination of the Unsullied on Obedience.

They find it easier to be killed or to kill themselves rather than disobeying a direct command from their masters.

From S03E01 on training of Unsullied:

> **Missandei**: They **begin their training at five**. Every day they drill
>   from dawn to dusk until they have mastered the shortsword, the shield,
>   and the three spears. Only one boy in four survives this rigorous
>   training. **Their discipline and loyalty are absolute**. They fear
>   nothing.

On Obedience Kraznys said this in the same episode:

> **Kraznys**: The Unsullied have stood here for a day and a night with no
>   food or water. They will stand until they drop. **Such is their**
>   **obedience**.

Then to demonstrate his point, Kraznys cuts off nipples of one of the Unsullied with the eunuch's own knife.

> **Kraznys**: She's worried about their nipples. Does
>   the dumb bitch know we've cut off their balls? [cuts off the nipple of
>   one of the Unsullied]
>
> **Missandei**: My master points out that men don't need nipples.
>
> **Kraznys**: Here, I'm done with you. [Gives the knife back]
>
> **Unsullied soldier**: This one is pleased to have
>   served you.

Later in S03E03, Daenerys questions Missandei about obedience of Unsullied:

> **Daenerys Targaryen**: Is it true what Master Kraznys told me about the
>   Unsullied? About their obedience?
>
> **Missandei**: All questions have been taken from them. They obey- that is
>   all. **Once they are yours, they are yours. They will fall on their
>   swords, if you command it**.

So you see, **It is their training on obedience according to the show as well which motivates the Unsullied to obey orders**. They start brainwashing the kids on obedience from age of 5 till they earn their caps. As a result, They will fall on their own swords if their master commands them to without thinking about disobedience. They will stand without food and water until they die if their master commands it.